# Execute script with get or post variables

Tags: php, curl

Ok, I'm pretty new at programming and have been using curl to execute scripts in other folders of my site and passing get and post variable that way.

Am I being stupid or is this the only way to do this?

Comment: This is probably not the only way to do this, but to tell for sure, we'd need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting way to do it but it's definitely overkill. You can just invoke the files with calls to [include](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). If those files require externally set variables, simply set them before including them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the only way to do this if the script is expecting get or post variables.

@Pekka why are you requesting code - it is a generic problem being asked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [PHP CLI](http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-tutorial.shtml) :)